# How to judge whether a method is implemented in parent class, and use it if so?

Tags: python

I have made a class `Stack`. I want to write code to detect whether the `pop` method is available in its parent. If so, call the parent version; otherwise, it should execute the child implementation of `pop`.

Here is some pseudo-code.

```
class Stack(list):
    # do some stuff here
    if has pop:
       use built-in method
    else
       #use mine implementation of code 
       def pop():
           # pop() impl.
```

Comment: You want to detect if the `pop()` method is available for what, do you mena for your object?

Comment: This is **what already happens** - if the method is implemented in the child class then that version is called, otherwise the parent class's version of the method is called. What exactly do you want?

Comment: I have attempted to clarify your question - please double-check to ensure that it still reflects what you want to know

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you can use built-in [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) function to check the existence of an attribute for an object :

example :

```
>>> hasattr(list,'pop')
True
>>> hasattr(tuple,'pop')
False
```

But about your question if you want to detect if the `pop()` method is available for parents you can use `hasattr` at implementation time and create your costume function under an `if` condition :

```
class A(object):
   def pop(self):
       return 'A: top'


class B(A):
        def pop(self):
           if not hasattr(super(B,self),'pop'):
               print 'pop' # or implement your costume function 
           return super(B,self).pop()
```

Demo:

```
print B().pop()
A: top
```

Comment: But that requires repeating the parent class name within the class definition

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, and what's wring with it?

Comment: That means that if you *change* the parent class, you then need to go through the rest of the class definition to update all of the conditionals as well. That's the problem with `super(ClassName, self)` in Python 2.x, too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Ohum, I didn't think about that, although It seems unlikely that there was a need to change the parent but, the `super` approach in 3.x is more efficient and better! thanks for noting that

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.  mybe we can use super like that: def       pop(self): if  hasattr(self,'pop'):return super(B,self).pop() else: print "pop"

Comment: @burcepa not like that, you can't; given that you're currently *inside* `self.pop`, how could `hasattr` ever be `False`?!

Comment: @  jonrsharpe  yes your are right,and how can i do this

Comment: @burcepan Are you in python 2.X?

Comment: @  Kasramvd  I use python2.7

Comment: @ if i change "hasattr(self,'pop')"  to "hasattr(super(B,self),'pop')",i think that will be work

Comment: That seems very awkward. You could factor out the second call to `super` with `getattr`, but the EAFP approach is much more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is **what already happens** in Python - if a method is implemented in a child class then that version is called, otherwise it attempts to find the method on the parent class (strictly, in the rest of the "method resolution order"). For example:

```
>>> class Parent(object):
    def implemented(self):
        print 'Parent.implemented'


>>> class Child(Parent):
    def not_implemented(self):
        print 'Child.not_implemented'


>>> c = Child()
>>> c.implemented()
Parent.implemented
>>> c.not_implemented()
Child.not_implemented
```

---

If you're *not sure* whether the `Parent` of your `Child` class implements a method `meth`, then you could use an [*"easier to ask forgiveness than permission"*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) approach to do the following:

```
class Child(Parent):

    def meth(self, ...):
        try:
            return super(Child, self).meth(...)  # attempt to call Parent version
        except AttributeError:
            ...  # implement Child version
```

However this means that your child could have a different interface from its parent, which interferes with [*"duck typing"*](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-duck-typing).

Comment: thank you very much, i think that is a good way to meet my requirement.